# css code doesn't apply to button in ionic 2

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, ionic2

I am new to ionic and hybrid apps in general. While plugging and playing with a teat app, i don't see any css working. What am I doing wrong?
Here's my files :
test.scss:

```
test{


.button-inner {
  width:20% !important;
  margin:30px;
}
}
```

Also, here's the respect test.html file:

```
<ion-content padding>
<button ion-button round class="button-inner">Submit</button>

</ion-content>
```

and I am referring to these classes in ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: 'test.html',
})
```

Not sure why the button is still taking up the entire width of the screen instead of just 20%. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem before, I think it's cause of Angular's view encapsulation ( aka shadow root). I've worked around it by doing something like this:

```
<ion-content padding>
<button ion-button round><span class="button-inner">Submit</span></button>

</ion-content>
```

Not entirely sure if this will give you your desired outcome since I haven't worked much with Ionic.

**EDIT**

After the conversation in the comments I created a working plnkr with the wanting behavior.

home.ts

```
import { Page, NavController } from 'ionic-angular/index';

@Page({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(private nav: NavController) {}
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button round class="custom-button button-inner">Submit</button>
</ion-content>
```

style.css

```
.custom-button {
  width: 20% !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/Ceb4CKzSFH9K6wiTO9tQ/)

Comment: thanks, that works great for me! However, to center the button, do i use :   align-self: center; in css?

Comment: when i exclusively mention style, i am able to do it, but not with css class reference : <button ion-button round style="width:40%;  margin-left: 30%;margin-top:5%">Submit</button>

Comment: @MarissaNicholas Interesting, I wonder if that's happening due to the css not finding the selector. To align center I would use flex-box.

Comment: even after adding span i dont see it working as expected, it just makes it the default size, i am not sure why this is happening