# Override * CSS property in scss Page

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2

I am learning ionic. In my app I want to make the font of linkbutton  to 12 px, however it is overridden by other css.
My  scss file has following css for linkbutton:

```
  .link_button {
  color: $myColor;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  bottom:10px;
  }
```

How can I make above scss to be implied forcibly on top of others ?

This is how text looks:

[image]

CSS which is implied in actual(got from chrome tool):

[image]

After suggestion from folks here I modified my scss file with both Id and Important  it did not work. 
When using important:(And same happens even if I do via Id)
[image]

Comment: Post the relevant html

Comment: This can't be. You're missing somthing. Specificity of `*` is less than Specificity of className.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a ID to the link button and specify the style using ID. This is because ID takes precedence over class styles

`#linkButton
{
Font-size:12px;
}`

Or you can use !important which will over write all other css styles. But be careful when you use it

`.linkButton
{
Font-size:12px !important;
}`

Comment: I tried both it does not work. Attaching screenshot, no option to upload picture in comment.

Comment: I added screenshot in my question.

Comment: Looks like Ion-button is overriding the font size if I remove ion-button attribute, it does work as expected.

Comment: try removing the page forgot password and just have class

Answer (score 0):

The best is not to use !important but to increase specificity. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

It was ionic-button who was adding button-inner class and it had default font size.
More on here:

[css code doesn't apply to button in ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416247/css-code-doesnt-apply-to-button-in-ionic-2)